# Get the name of each tag in XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I have to process an XML file with following format:

```
<Root>
<A name="x1">
    <B exp="h1", ref="r1"/>
    <C exp="h2", ref="r2", rat = "ra1"/>
    <D exp="h3", ref="r3"/>
</A>
<A name="x2">
    <E exp="h4", ref="r4"/>
    <F exp="h5", ref="r5"/>
</A>
</Root>
```

I want to write an stored procedure to get a table like:

```
|A_name|tag_name|attrbute|val|
|x1    |   B    |exp|h1|
|x1    |   B    |ref|r1|
|x1    |   C    |exp|h2|
|x1    |   C    |rat|ra1|
|x1    |   C    |ref|r2|
|x1    |   D    |exp|h3|
|x1    |   D    |ref|r3|
|x2    |   E    |exp|h4|
|x2    |   E    |ref|r4|
|x2    |   F    |exp|h5|
|x2    |   F    |ref|r5|
```

How can I do? Since I am using `OPENXML` in other parts of that stored procedure, so it is best to use `OPENXML` function to get it.

I've already try

```
SELECT localname
FROM OPENXML(@idoc, '/A') 
WHERE localname!='A'
```

to get the tag name. However, I am not able to join them with attribute of tag A.

Comment: What have you tried? (Edit your question to include the SQL you tried.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to say: `FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used anymore (rare exceptions exist). Better use the [native XML methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-ver15) of the XML data type.

Second to say: Your XML is - strictly spoken - not well formed. There should be one single root element, while there are several `<A>` elements on the first level. Gladfully SQL-Server allows for XML fragments. So this will work...

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<A name="x1">
    <B/>
    <C/>
    <D/>
</A>
<A name="x2">
    <E/>
    <F/>
</A>';

SELECT AllA.value('@name','varchar(100)') AS A_name
      ,Children.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS tag_name
FROM @xml.nodes('/A') A(AllA)
OUTER APPLY AllA.nodes('*') B(Children);
```

The idea in short:

- We use `.nodes()` to retrieve the repeated `<A>` elements
- We use `.value()` to read the `name` attribute from `<A>`
- We use `APPLY` with another `.nodes()` call to retrieve all elements below `<A>`.
- Now we can use `.value()` with `local-name()` to read the element's name.

Comment: thank you so much! But there are still a problem, could you help me out? I have updated it in the question.